# Partnership Tax Return UK

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, partnership

We started a partnership in the UK on 20th March 2017 and are ceasing it today (14th July 2017).

As of yet we have yet to send in any tax returns for 2016/2017.

Would it be permissible to file one tax return for the partnership to cover 20/03/2017 to 14/04/2017 considering they are two different tax years, or would I have to do the 16/17 now and 17/18 next year?